# pdflatex: changing rendering depending on print/display

Tags: pdftex

So e.g. hyperref does paint this ugly boxes around links by default which are not included when printing the document. Can I *deliberately* implement similar behaviour in my LaTeX document (i.e. prints a slightly different version from what is displayed)?

Comment: only in limited ways (search this site for `ocg`)  the link border is special as the drawing of them by the pdf viewer and dropping them on print is not something tex is controling it's just how pdf applications treat pdf link borders.

Comment: that helps! `ocg` is the correct keyword, thank you!